# matSelect - matOption: Adjust amount of options shown (default 6 options are shown)

Tags: angular, angular-material, select-options

I use this angular material component in my Angular 5 application:

[matSelect with search](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-mat-select-search)

and 6 options are show by default.
Is there a way of adjust it in order to e.g. 4 options are shown by default?

```
<mat-form-field style="width:88%;margin-top:5px;">
    <mat-select formControlName="contact" placeholder="Kontakt *">
        <ngx-mat-select-search [formControl]="contactFilter"></ngx-mat-select-search>
        <mat-option *ngFor="let contact of filteredContacts | async" [value]="contact" style="max-height:50px;">
            {{contact.institution}} - {{contact.address.postalCode}} {{contact.address.region}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Paste some code please.

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the options shown when initializing `filteredContacts` similar to the [example](https://stackblitz.com/github/bithost-gmbh/ngx-mat-select-search-example)

```
// load the initial contact list
this.filteredContacts.next(contacts.slice(0, 4));
```

If you are asking how to limit the amount of visible options, i.e. the height of the option panel, you can update `ngx-mat-select-search` to the latest version, since in `1.4.1` an override of the panel height was removed due to positioning problems, see https://github.com/bithost-gmbh/ngx-mat-select-search/releases/tag/1.4.1